# Camera tips for Smartphones

Tags: camera-basics, smartphone

I have a 5-megapixels camera (smartphone) which is not quite clear while taking photos. Please tell me some tips to capture clear and professional photos :)

Comment: At the moment, this is too broad for us to be able to give a useful answer. Could you try and refine the question to concentrate on one specific aspect of your photos that you're trying to improve?

Comment: If you would like useful answers, you will have to be specific i.e. what is the smartphone, what situations are you taking photos in, what in particular do you not like about the photos? If possible please also post a link to some sample photos. All of this should go in the main question body, not as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few tips that may help improve your Smartphone Photography.

Always aim to shoot in brightly lit areas, or if indoors, light your subject well. Buy some cheap Clamp lamps for $10 each at Home Depot, Ikea Etc. they will be a good start.

Steady your camera. this is one of the main causes for bad photos as there is quite often a shutter lag in Phone Cameras and people tend to move before the phone camera has completed the process of the capture.

Rest your camera on something to give it extra steadiness

Getting real close to your subject will cause the background to go out of focus and create a subjectively, a more pleasing shot

Never, Never, Never use the camera Digital Zoom. That is a sure fire way to reduce the quality of your image

use the rule of 3rd's - The phone will have a grid, try to place your subject on the intersection of the gridlines and not always in the middle

It maybe obvious, but always use the highest res available on the camera as this will help with any required cropping later on the Computer

This brings me to the editing, use a good computer software to edit as you will most likely get better results than off the phone software and the on board filters.

Finally, take as many photos of the same subject from as many different angles and perspectives as possible and play with the white balance feature if your camera has that

Comment: Getting “really close” doesn't have a big effect on the background blur but does make people really ugly due to perspective effects visible within the depth of the face.

Comment: @jdlugosz - Getting real close to your subject, the background will eventually blur out. This is great for certain types of photography where perspective distortion may not be too much of a concern. I.E flowers, insects small animals, certain types of stock photography, albeit, only at close distance where any perspective distortion can be viewed as an artistic interpretation. Your concern about people, whilst subjective, can also be used to artistic effect as it can boil down to angles and perspectives that minimise the unwanted distortion. give it a go, its real fun.

Comment: On a tiny cell phone lens, just how much is the background blurred? Ah, I can find out [here](http://dofsimulator.net/en/?f=6&a=2.8&d=0&s=1%2F2.5%22&y0=427&y=16459&b=1&c=f&l=0&e=0&m=girl1&t=drzewo&o=l&k=1600&g=0). Subject distance is 15 inches and the nominal dof just gets the ears if focused on an eye (4 in back), *but* the tree in the background isn't thrown out of focus in the manner I normally tink using that effect, but is just slightly blurry, in a 8x12in print.

Comment: @jdlugosz - Hey, thats a great tool. thanks of that. I have bookmarked it for future use. If you get a chance, check out www.ippawards.com- It has some great iPhone camera images on there.